# How can I download SPSS v20 full version for 64 bit

Tags: download, spss

How can I download SPSS v20 full version for 64 bit. Please share if anybody knows the url

Answer (score 1):

Downloading SPSS installation files can be done via IBM's [Passport Advantage](http://m.ibm.com/http/www-01.ibm.com/software/passportadvantage/pacustomers.html) portal, amongst other account related actions.

Note if you have trial version installed already then it is a case of generating appropriate licence keys for your module subscriptions to gain access. The installation  files for trial and full versions are no different.

Comment: I did not found any download link here  http://m.ibm.com/http/www-01.ibm.com/software/passportadvantage/pacustomers.html  if i can get Trial version of spss 20 its ok as well. I searched but i can get spss 19 trial version not 20

Comment: Not directly, you won't. Registering/logging in and navigating to the appropriate section then only you will.